# Response.Write and postbacks in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

As I understand it, in ASP.NET, when a control does a postback, a request for the same page (i.e. the page from which the request came) is sent to the server, then the server sends a response, a http output stream, to the client. This stream contains the requested page.

When you use `Response.Write()` in ASP.NET, you also write to the response http output stream.

My question is then : where do the things you write in a `Response.Write()` fit in a standard postback stream flow, are they always added at the beginning of the postback response stream, before anything else on the page, or does it work differently ?

Comment: FYI, that's not specific to postback. The exact same things happen on the initial GET of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you call it in the page [life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx). The output can end up anywhere on the page. I don't recommend using `Response.Write()` in ASP.NET. Instead, use a server control like `asp:Panel`, `asp:Literal`, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you be a bit more specific; where does it ends relative to when you call it ? It seems if i do a Response.Write() in an event handler of a postback enabled control, it ends up at the very beginning of the (posted back) page, before anything else; when does it end elsewhere ?

Comment: This is because all controls are rendered after all postback events are handled. But if you add `Response.Rewrite` in an event of a control (for example `OnLoad` for an `asp:Label` control) it will be rendered in a different position (below that previous position). See [this diagram](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/01/14/asp-net-page-life-cycle-diagram.aspx) for more details.